# What pattern or principle to use, in order to simplify generation of content that is based on lot of parameters?

Tags: design-patterns, conditional-statements, simplify, design-principles

In a situation, where you need to generate a bunch of `<title>`, `<meta name="description">` and `<h1>` tag contents, based on many query search parameters for thousands of pages. What principle or pattern is best fit in a situation like that?

For example:

You will get some array with lot's of query parameters, like the type of some object, it's features, location and many more. Based on the parameters, you need to generate, translate and render, different content in tags. What to do to avoid too many if statements and switch cases.

I am aware that I could replace conditional with polymorphism, but still, when I get all those parameters, I need to somehow check for all possibilities and determine context what I will use. Then I am faced with a bunch of if statements, checking is some value set, what value does it have etc. Too many condition checking. Basically, that array I get is my huge problem, because I have to check every value if it exists or not. Unfortunately that params that come in an array shape, can't be turned to the class. So I have to stick with an array.

**EDIT:** I could take my array and map it to object representation of it, is it a better approach? How can I make most of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way you described problem statement at high level - looks you might need builder with decorator pattern.

**For example**: You will have separate components called decorators. Like one responsible for creating header, other for tags and one for titles etc. Depending upon various parameters, you builder should give you object decorated with various components (for example : wrap content within tags, then wrap content with tags within title etc.)

Look at decorator and builder pattern examples for more clarity.

Also it is good to look for examples and designs applied in similar situations. For example : while reading your problem statement, I was able to co-relate with similarities in WPF application where XAML content/elements act as a decorator elements and combined together to form complete visual representation.